# StaleElementException while writing a text file in python using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to scrape the reviews of a hotel from TripAdvisor and write it in a text file. So far the code is doing good except the fact that every now and then it throws StaleElementException on the line where I am writing the text file. Here's is my code:

```
for num in range(page_count):
    try:
        if num != 0:
            try:
                nxt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk")))
                #nxt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk")
                nxt.click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                driver.refresh()
                #driver.implicitly_wait(5)
                nxt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk")))
                nxt.click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        try:
            more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")))
            #more = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")
            more.click()
            time.sleep(1)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("There is no 'more' button on page %d" % (num+1))
        except WebDriverException:
            nxt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")))
            nxt.click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        review_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry')))

        with open('New_Review.txt', 'a') as fid:
            for review in review_result:
                    fid.write(unidecode(review.text))
                    fid.write(sep)
                    fid.write(line_break)
        print ("processing done till page number %d" % (num+1))
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        driver.refresh()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        try:
            more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")))
            #more = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")
            more.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            print("There is no 'more' button on page %d" % (num+1))
        except WebDriverException:
            nxt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")))
            nxt.click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        review_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry')))

        #print (review_result[1].text)
        with open('New_Review.csv', 'a') as fid:
            writer = csv.writer(fid, delimiter = ',', line_break = '\n')
            for review in review_result:
                    fid.write(unidecode(review.text))
                    fid.write(sep)
                    fid.write(line_break)
        print ("processing done till page number %d" % (num+1))
```

Here is the error:

> StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is
>   not attached to the page document

The traceback gives this line:

```
fid.write(unidecode(review.text))
```

I have already tried to handle the exception but its not working for me and I am having a hard time trying to figure out where exactly am I wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I use beautiful soup and xpath. Selenium is a little flakey for scraping. I use it for testing, but only because it has some builtin things that are handy.

Comment: I plan on using BeautifulSoup but this code is giving me a hard time as I am not able to understand the fault here.

Comment: Hi use WATIR(wrapper of Ruby selenium binding), you will never face stale element problem because WATIR rebuild the element if element goes stale.

Comment: Thanks Gopal, could you direct me to a some link where I can get some details around this - not aware of Ruby framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating helper method such as

```
def get_text(locator):
   staled = True
   while staled:
     try:
        return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element(locator)).text
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
       `log something or limit retry to certain times`
```

then change how you get the text

```
review_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located())
num_of_review - review_result.length
        with open('New_Review.txt', 'a') as fid:
            for index in range(1, num_of_review):
                    review_text = get_text((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='entry'][index]"))
                    fid.write(unidecode(review_text))
                    fid.write(sep)
                    fid.write(line_break)
```

Comment: I am getting an undefined name error in the `get_text` method.

Comment: could you paste error stack trace?   some of the syntax that I wrote need to be completed or fix, but the idea is that you need to get element directly and retrieving the text, since I think maybe your page changes wile ypu retrieving text which causing stale exception

Comment: I can't paste stack trace as its a compile time error - so I see this message when I write this function in Spyder. But I get your point, I am just trying to find out what is the syntax here for `get_text` method.

Comment: hmm, the syntax that is wrong is related with expected conditions, have you changed the line like this?
`...
 review_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
return review_element.text` 

and on exception handling

Comment: But if I write `EC.presence_of_element_located(locator)` wouldn't it pick just one review entry and not the list!

Comment: yes, that's why there is loop `for index in range(1, num_of_review):` to reget all elements one by one, this should minimise staleelement issue

Comment: OK, so I should try a code like this `review_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry')))
return review_result.text
num_of_review = review_result.length
        with open('New_Review.txt', 'a') as fid:
            for index in range(1, num_of_review):
                    review_text = get_text((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='entry'][index]"))
                    fid.write(unidecode(review_text))
                    fid.write(sep)
                    fid.write(line_break)` right? let me know if I misunderstood!

Comment: This is frustrating - now the return statement is giving me an indent error: If I write it just below the `review_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry')))` it says `return` outside function. And if I write it after a tab it says unexpected indent.

Comment: Do I need to create a function for this?

Comment: what editor did you use to write the code?  I don't think you need to create function for that, although if it is used more than once, then it is a good way to reduce code duplication
on indentation error might means you incorrectly indent the code, maybe you need to use some python validator for this to show you which is incorrect
and remove this line `return review_result.text` i miss to identify this one

Comment: I am using Spyder. If I remove `return review_result.text` from the code that I pasted above, it gives me the same error again for `get_text` as undefined name.